# Build errors in node-modules after updating Vue package, i18next

Tags: typescript, vue.js, node-modules, i18next

I am trying to update i18n package to the new version i18next.
After updating, I got a lot of errors during project compilation. The solution that I found was to add skipLibCheck to compiler options in tsconfig file. That fixed the compilation errors and everything is working fine.
Now I am facing the issue, that the errors which were appearing during compilation are failing my application build.

Is there any way to omit typescript checking the node_modules folder during the vue-cli-service build?

In tsconfig.json I have already added:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
```

and

```
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules/*",
  ]
```

Example errors:
[image]

Comment: same problem. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This solution is relevant when using vue-cli

```js
# vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
     config.plugin('fork-ts-checker').tap(args => {
      args[0].checkSyntacticErrors = false;
      return args;
    });
  }
}
```